# Sub setting a multi level dataframe by the top values for each second level index in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subset, multi-level

I have a multilevel index dataframe that looks like the image below. I have sorted the second level index on the higher of the perc_viewed column. So for each 1st level index, the higher of Male(M) or Female(F) is listed first. Now I want to access just the 1st level index values and the first of the second level index value (the top one) -- only those two and use them in my write up for my analysis as the "top" in each category. How may I do this please

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfxEp.png)

Another view of this data is as below. In this case the values appearing first that I have highlighted are the only ones that I want to access.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNNju.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Reproduce the data from your post:

```
arrays = [
    np.array(["informational_0_0_4", "informational_0_0_4", "informational_0_0_3", "informational_0_0_3", "discount_5_20_10", "discount_5_20_10", "discount_3_7_7", "discount_3_7_7"]),
    np.array(["F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "M", "F", "M"]),
]

data = {'event':[2797, 3860, 3805, 2838, 2849, 3877, 2773, 3882],'viewed_count':[1551, 1936, 3433, 2440, 1010, 1205, 2669, 3710]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=arrays)

df['perc_viewed'] = (df['viewed_count']*100/df['event']).round(2)
df
```

Here's the approach that fetches the max value from `level=0` **after you already sorted `df`in descending order**.

```
df.groupby(level=0).head(1)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you. This is a very effective and yet clean way to do this. I appreciate. It works for my needs, and then to reference the index that I want I simply use this format, df.index[0][0], df.index[0][1],.... df.index[2][0]. A pity I can't upvote your solution as I am still new here, but thank you..

Comment: Yeap, never mind~